# Can't 17 give energy to Goku to restore Goku's power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the tournament of power we've seen Freezer giving energy to Goku to restore Goku's power, after he run out of energy when he used for the first time incomplete Ultra Instinct

[image]

Then in Dragon Ball Z we've seen how 17 gave energy to Goku for him to create a Genki Dama

[image]

Since 17 has infinite energy, why cant he give energy to Goku to restore his energy just like Freezer did before?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the Energy given for the **Spirit Bomb** is different from the Energy given by Freiza and Vegeta to Goku. Goku can gather this energy from *inanimate life forms and surrounding objects* as well for the spirit bomb. Hence, in other words, Goku can't gather energy from a rock and regain stamina.
Secondly, the androids have infinite "Stamina" which prevents them from getting tired like a normal individual. This might be because of mechanical part fitted inside Android 17. So it would be impossible for Android 17 to share his energy with Goku. 
A better analogy would be something like this.

Let us assume there exist 2 human beings and 1 robot.

Human beings need x amount of blood to survive while the robot has a fitted energy source which is different from blood but always keeps them alive.

If one human is deprived of blood, he needs to rely on the other human and can't ask help from the robot despite him having an infinite energy source because the human has a different anatomy compared to the robot.

Comment: I understand what you mean but it's there any source for that? At least in non canon movies it seems Goku can use genki dama energy to power up, as he did in the movie Super Android 13. BTW, the term inanimate life is a contradiction. Inanimate means lifeless, inanimate life would mean lifeless life.

Comment: The movies are non-canonical.

Comment: @Pablo I understand what inanimate means. Goku can also gather energy from inanimate objects like mountains. How would that be a contradiction? The Second statement with regard to 17 is unrelated to the first. The first was differntiate the difference between the energy of a spirit bomb and stamina.

Comment: @Pablo Based on your logic, if the Spirt Bomb energy and Healing Energy is the same, then Senzu Beans shouldn't just heal a character but it should also increase their level of strength. The Senzu beans merely replenish their stamina completely.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 I dont mean that, but one movie showed that. I dont say that counts, because as it was pointed by Krazer and myself in my first post, the movies are non canon, yet non canon story elements has been canonized before just like the final kamehameha from the videogames, so it's something to have in mind, because it's a possible argument they could canonize

Comment: @Pablo Well We saw Goku take a full spirit bomb head on in Episode 110  and in the process was almost killed and was in so much trouble that he was forced to break out of his potential and achieve a level of power even the Gods struggle to achieve. So the Spirit Bomb powering up Goku after all that seems very unlikely. Also, the Spirit Bomb honestly has nothing to do with this question. Android 17's energy source is mechanical while Goku has a Saiyan anatomy(Which isn't very different from that of a humans).